# Sum of time in Google Sheets' chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I tried to show a chart where the values are the sum of times. It looks ok in the spreadsheet with for example 19 hours and 25 hours but in the chart, the 19 is ok but the 25 is shown as 1. The format in the chart is "time on a day" not the sum of time.

Anyone who knows how it can be correct?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score -1):

I found out myself that if I changed the format of the time-column to "[h]:mm;;" then the diagram was correct.